# Is it true that $\int_{\Omega} u^2\leq \alpha \int_{\Omega} |Du|^2$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Let $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is a bounded open set in $\Bbb{R}^2$. Is the following true:

> For some $\alpha>0$, $\int_{\Omega} u^2\leq \alpha \int_{\Omega} |Du|^2$

I remember reading this somewhere, but can't quite recall where. Note that $u\equiv 0$ at the boundary. I think I read it in Evans' book but can't find it now

Comment: Look up Poincare's inequality

Comment: @CalvinKhor- Thanks!!!!